# Remove everything before and after a word that begins with "@" in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have an Ifttt setup that writes to a Google Sheet. The content of the cell, directly from the source, is a sentence. Right now I'm manually cleaning up the cells as they come in but since this is a recurring sheet that generates content it's been time consuming.

The content will always have "@" with the word after it. Examples:

```
Here is an @example lol words here
@AnotherExample or this
```

Is there a formula to take all the content before and after the @ so the result should be:

```
example
AnotherExample
```

I kept trying the =REGEXREPLACE formula but I can't seem to make it work for my use case. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: are there more than 1 instances of @XYZ in one cell?

Comment: @player0 not every time but sometimes

Comment: if so, then the accepted answer wont work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"@(\S*)")
```

- `@` - Match a literal "@".
- `(\S*)` - 0+ non-whitespace characters captured in a group.

`REGEXEXTRACT()` Will then extract this capture group. You could also use `@(\w*)` to capture 0+ word characters. if your input can be something like "test1 @test2, test3".

Thrown in an array variant:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="","",REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"@(\w*)")),)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you SOOO much!! That is wonderful. I used this as my final formula and its flawless: =REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE),"@(\S*)") (it uses the cell to the left of the formula to source the text "-1") for anyone looking into this for the future